# ¿Como sacar la superficie y perímetro utilizando Google Maps en un rango?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, canvas

Si se fijan en la siguiente imagen hay un rango seleccionado utilizando las herramientas de dibujo de [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools?hl=es-419):

[image: Rango superficie imagen]

Lo que me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma o si pueden darme algún tutorial manual o como leer para poder sacar la superficie y el perímetro del área que seleccione utilizando esta herramienta.

Answer (score 1):

Para esto tienes que cargar la biblioteca de geometría de google maps. Esto significa que, en vez del script usual:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY>
</script>
```

Hay que añadir `geometry` a las bibliotecas adicionales

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry">
</script>
```

La incorporación de esta biblioteca añade funciones adicionales al espacio de nombres `google.maps`. En particular, para tu caso de uso, dado un polígono:

```
var poligono=new google.maps.Polygon({...});
```

La biblioteca permite obtener área y perímetro como:

```
var area= google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(poligono.getPath());
var perimetro= google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(poligono.getPath());
```

Como verás, hay un aspecto no abordado en la pregunta que es *cómo obtener la referencia a un polígono que acabas de dibujar* con [google.maps.DrawingManager](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DrawingManager).

La única manera de hacer eso es tener un listener en el DrawingManager esperando al evento `polygoncomplete`, que recibe como argumento dicha referencia. Los polígonos dibujados que no captures escuchando ese evento no quedan por así decirlo en un array global que puedas acceder después.